# 'Graph' object has no attribute 'nodes_iter' in networkx module python

Tags: python, networkx

I have the below function in python2.7 using networkx module which produces the error.

```
for H in networkx.connected_component_subgraphs(G):
    bestScore = -1.0
    for n, d in H.nodes_iter(data=True):
        if d['Score'] > bestScore:
            bestScore = d['Score']
            bestSV = n
    if bestSV is not None:
        selectedSVs.add(bestSV)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cnvClassifier.py", line 128, in <module>
for n, d in H.nodes_iter(data=True):
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'nodes_iter'
```

Does anybody have any idea what has been wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are probably using the pre-release version of networkx-2.0 which has removed the nodes_iter() method and now provides the the nodes() method with the same functionality.
See [this](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/release/release_2.0.html) for details on the networkx-2.0 changes.

Comment: This should be it now: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.0.html

Comment: Also link to [Migration Guide from 1.x to 2.0](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html)

Answer (score 10):

Just in case the link changes again, I'm going to post the actual solution here for future reference.

From NetworkX 2.0 forward, you should change the following line of code from:

```
for n, d in H.nodes_iter(data=True):
```

to:

```
for n, d in list(H.nodes(data=True)):
```

Comment: I'm facing with this error : TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'